# Help me optimize my work

Tags: finance

I am a physician. I am required to work 14 shifts per month.
I may work extra shifts for 1400 dollars per shift.
In addition, I earn productivity based on a system called RVUs.
For every RVU I produce over 4100 for the year, I will earn an additional 30 dollars
If I average 33 RVUs per shift, what is the optimal number of shifts to work to earn an additional gross 100,000 dollars per year from all sources?

Comment: If you are a physician, you can afford to hire an accountant, who will be glad to answer this question for you.

Comment: The raw answer is you should work $192$ shifts per year, or 16 shifts per month.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If there were accounting.stackexchange.com, I wonder how many accountants there would be willing to answer idiotic, er, I mean naive questions for free.

Comment: @Igor, maybe we should propose such a site, see how it goes.

Comment: @Gerry sure, though I am none too confident...

Comment: A tagline for the site is "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions". In that spirit, I feel personal comments should be avoided in favor of answers or opinions about the merit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

$100000=\left(S-14\times12\right)\times1400+\left(33S-4100\right)\times30\implies S\approx192$

You must work **192** shifts per year.